# Android: Set minimum height of a view programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set minimum height for an imageview programmatically but had no luck so far. My code is below

```
    int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 160, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int minHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    SmartImageView siv = new SmartImageView(getActivity());
    siv.setMinimumHeight(minHeight);
    siv.setLayoutParams(sivParams);
    siv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    siv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    siv.setImageUrl(url);
    ll.addView(siv);
```

I also tried to put the setMinimumWidth method after the setLayoutParams method but that didn't worked either. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Are params and sivParams the same (is it a typing error or 2 actually different variables)? Also, are you using the correct type of LayoutParams? If the parent view for siv is a RelativeLayout, you need to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, if it's a LinearLayout - LinearLayout.LayoutParams and so on..

Comment: sorry that was a type error and also i was using the same ie LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Note for future readers like me: If you have a minHeight set in XML, it seems that trying to change it in code doesn't work (Android 4.x testing).  If you remove it from your XML, you can then set it in code, and even change it (set multiple times to different values).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer by *@Ashok Damani* is **incorrect** as pointed out by @*Gustavo Baiocchi Costa* in the comments:

> this sets the height or width not the minimum width or height

The **correct method** to set the minimum height of a view in Android:

Property access way(in **Kotlin**):

```
yourView.minimumHeight = minHeight
```

Setter method way:

```
yourView.setMinimumHeight(minHeight);
```

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setMinimumHeight(int)) says:

> Sets the minimum height of the view. It is not guaranteed the view
> will be able to achieve this minimum height (for example, if its
> parent layout constrains it with less available height).

Answer (score 12):

try this--->

```
siv.getLayoutParams().height = minHeight;
```

or u can also try--->

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width , minHeight);
siv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Actually, i have text beside of the imageview and the height is of the imageview will be dynamically changed based on the amount of text. But if there is no text, i want to set a minimum height for the imageview because, if there is no text, then the imageview will have 0 height

Comment: this sets the height or width not the minimum width or height