# Set minHeight of LinearLayout Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

This is my code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minHeight="1000dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set the minHeight of linear layout in xml. But I want to set it programmatically. I have two cards in this linear layout. And **I want to set the minHeight on the basis of my two cards height**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Set minimum height of a view programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790902/android-set-minimum-height-of-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: @Sanket did you tried my solution

Comment: @sanky I am trying your solution. thanks for the answer

Comment: ok let me know if it works

Comment: @sanky sorry bro it not worked.. but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `View.setMinimumHeight()`

check more details on developer.android :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)

Answer (score 2):

// yourView - is view you want to use

//minHeight - your minimum hieght you want to set

```
  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, minHeight);
    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```